# Single OnClickListener for multiple ViewHolders

Tags: android

My `ViewHolder` (inner) class:

```
static class HostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageButton button1;
    ImageButton button2;

    HostViewHolder(View listItemView) {
        super(listItemView);

        button1 = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    }
}
```

In `onBindViewHolder()` i attach `OnClickListener`s to the `Button`s the following way:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HostViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            // doing something using the value of pos
        }
    });
    holder.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            // doing some other thing using the value of pos
        }
    });
}
```

It's working fine, but my problem with this approach is i'm creating a new `OnClickListener` instance for every `ViewHolder`, which feels kinda redundant.

I would like to create a **single** `OnClickListener` instance to use, but i cannot access the `position` and `holder` params of `onBindViewHolder()` that way.

Is this possible to achieve? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you want a single listener for button1 and button2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach onClickListener in the ViewHolder class itself.

```
static class HostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageButton button1;
    ImageButton button2;

    HostViewHolder(View listItemView) {
        super(listItemView);

        button1 = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        switch (v.getId()){
            //handle clicks
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible and you can achieve it, as @Gurupad suggested, using switch statement in `onClick(View v)` method. And from personal experience its the best way to handle more than one onClicks, it makes your code easy to read and understand for you and your team (if working with a team).

For further assistance using switch statement with buttons click

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
     case R.id.button1:
     //some code here
     break;
     case R.id.button2:
     //some code here
     break;
  }
}
```